# Open a new browser session in a different window in Selenium

Tags: selenium-ide

I am new to Selenium and just started to use it. I want to open a new browser session in a different window from my script and do not know how to do it.

I tried using the open command and gave the Firefox Url but it opened in the same window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using openWindow instead of open.  If you get a message that Firefox blocked a popup, allow popups.  This will probably open a tab instead of a window, but maybe that will suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void Test01() throws Exception {
openTab("http://www.xyz.com");
}
```

This will open a different Firefox window. And then Handle to switch the new window.

```
public void trigger(String script, WebElement element) {
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, element);
}

public Object trigger(String script) {
return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script);
}

public void openTab(String url) {
String script = "var d=document,a=d.createElement('a');a.target='_blank';a.href='%s';a.innerHTML='.';d.body.appendChild(a);return a";
Object element = trigger(String.format(script, url));
if (element instanceof WebElement) {
WebElement anchor = (WebElement) element;
anchor.click();
trigger("var a=arguments[0];a.parentNode.removeChild(a);", anchor);
} else {
throw new JavaScriptException(element, "Unable to open Window", 1);
}
}
```